# Maintenance mode just for WooCommerce shop pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to enable some sort of maintenance mode for a Woocommerce site.  The problem is all of the maintenance mode plugins I have seen designed for both WordPress and specifically for WooCommerce just target the entire site.

I want to target just the shop pages.

I have looked and all of the woocommerce pages have a body tag of woocommerce-page

Can anyone point me in the direction of a snippet to just target pages by body tag and allow me to hide the content and replace with a custom message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this snippet below to your themes functions file to create the message you want displayed. (For all Woocommerce conditional options, visit their codex here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/)

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'royal_woocommerce_maintenance');
function royal_woocommerce_maintenance($content) {
   if( is_woocommerce() or is_shop() or is_product_category() or is_product() or is_cart() or is_checkout() or is_account_page() ) {
      $content.= '<div style="border:1px dotted #000; text-align:center; padding:10px;">';
      $content.= '<h4>We will be back soon</h4>';
      $content.= '<p>We are down for maintenance, please check back soon.</p>';
      $content.= '</div>';
   }
   return $content;
}
```

Then in your CSS file you can target the classes or ID you wish to hide so for example

```
.products, .product {
    display: none !important;
}
```

You could obviously streamline this a little and turn it into a cool little maintenance mode plugin for Woocommerce and customize the look, message, etc but this should be enough to get you close to what you after for now :-)

**UPDATE:**

I created a plugin for this, [WooCommerce Maintenance Mode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-maintenance-mode/).

I have created a few options for displaying content, using redirects, adjusting frequency of messages & redirects and setting an expiration for the maintenance mode to deactivate automatically.

I will be adding more features soon! You can find it under plugins on [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-maintenance-mode/)

Please rate it and if you have any ideas or suggestions, please pass them along to me so we I make it even better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but should work:

Add the following code to it the top of your header.php, after the < body > tag:

```
<?php if(is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() || is_cart() ) {
 echo 'Maintenance Mode';
}
?>
```

I am using the [woocommerce conditional tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) to check if you're on one of the pages, if we are then it displays the error. You can add any html etc to funk it up where the echo '' is.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it should be possible by using woocommerce specific [conditional tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/), like `is_woocommerce()` and `is_checkout()`, to target the woocommerce pages. And by replacing [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) via [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter. That's just a quick draft of an approach, see @mattroyal's answer for an outlined solution.